# Magento 2: convert curl response into array

Tags: magento-2.1.3, curl

I am not able to convert magento 2 JSON response into array. Can you please help in short out this problem?

Here is my code:

```
$url = 'http://example.com/api/coop';
$post = [
        'firstname' => $userDetail->firstname,
        'lastname'  => $userDetail->lastname,
        'email'     => $userDetail->email,
        'password'  => $userDetail->password
    ];
$this->curlClient->post($url, $post);
$responseCurl = $this->curlClient->getBody();
print_r($responseCurl);
die();
```

Output:

```
{"coop_id":"COOP33"}
```

I have to use `coop_id` value somewhere in my logic. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can check in PHP sandbox, example below.
[Show example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/eb19ecd302448ed99b903fbdd8a8225bab5873ca)

```php
<?php

$jsonString = '{"coop_id":"COOP33"}';

$stdClass = json_decode($jsonString);
echo $stdClass->coop_id; //COOP33

$array = json_decode($jsonString, true);
echo $array['coop_id']; //COOP33
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **json_decode** as follows.

```
<?php
    $json = $responseCurl;    
    $array = json_decode($json, true);
    $coop_id = $array['coop_id'];
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply soon! But its not working for me.

Comment: use var_dump(json_decode($json, true)); to see your values.

Comment: @PankajSharma  Did you assign response to $json variable ?

Comment: @KishanPatadia I am sending curl response in JSON format.

Comment: @PankajSharma Please try updated answer code

Comment: @KishanPatadia sorry its not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $json = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';

var_dump(json_decode($json));           // Object
var_dump(json_decode($json, true));     // Associative array
```